# Trying to use Task to update a JavaFX scene graph, getting errors on calls to event handlers outside the task object

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a small folder/image browser in JavaFX. (Note - I'm using Java 8)

It currently displays folders by going through the folder's contents, finding any images, picking 4 of them at random, and then displaying those images along with the folder name.

If there are lots of folders with lots of images in a given parent folder, this process can take a fairly long time.

I'm trying to change the code to display each folder and its selected images one at a time as the method goes through them, rather than all at once after the method finishes running.

From what I've gotten out of looking into how to do this, the typical approach to something like this is to take your code and put it into a Task object, then run the task in a separate thread, using the Platform.runlater method to do object updates on the original FX Application thread, like:

```
 final Group group = new Group();
 Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
     @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
             if (isCancelled()) break;
             final Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10);
             r.setX(10 * i);
             Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override public void run() {
                     group.getChildren().add(r);
                 }
             });
         }
         return null;
     }
 };
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

However, the code I'd like to update contains two setOnMouseClicked events, imageView.setOnMouseClicked(this::folderImageClick) and myFolder.setOnMouseClicked(this::folderClick). that call handlers written outside of the task. In terms of the above example I guess it would be

```
 final Group group = new Group();
 Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
     @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
         for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
             if (isCancelled()) break;
             final Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10);
             r.setX(10 * i);
             r.setOnMouseClicked(this::mouseEventHandler);
             Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override public void run() {
                     group.getChildren().add(r);
                 }
             });
         }
         return null;
     }
 };
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

When I do this, I get the errors

> The method `setOnMouseClicked(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent>)` in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments `(this::folderImageClick)`

and

> The type `new Task<Void>(){}` does not define `folderImageClick(MouseEvent)` that is applicable here

Is there way to fix the event handler calls so that they work inside of Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` points to the `Task` when used from a method of the task. Obviously there is no `mouseEventHandler` in your anonymus class. You need to use a reference to the outer class containing the method. Assuming the name of the class is `OuterClass`:

```
OuterClass.this::mouseEventHandler
```